# Is SE working on any other products, like forum or polling tools?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Since StackExchange has utterly nailed the Q&A format, I'm just wondering if they are working on any other products?

Context:
I recently posted a question to the UX (user experience) site asking for examples of a particular kind of GUI. It hasn't been removed yet, but I know the question doesn't conform to the Q&A format. Nonetheless, I think the question has merit.  In this circumstance, a simple modification to the Q&A format to permit more than one correct answer would create a new kind of site, call it the brainstorming format. Feature extensions to the domain of opinion polls could be amazing. Etc etc.

Comment: Who or what is SA?

Comment: if you're building a car, you are building a car. If you are building a truck, you are building a truck. The quickest way to ruin a car is to try to strap a truck bed on it for 'the best of both worlds'

Comment: @JeffAtwood - That makes good sense, and Q&A is big enough to accommodate more in the future. Well, how  about maybe keeping the idea on the back-burner though?

Comment: I think you can safely ask questions like you asked("i'm looking for a product that does XYZ"), as long as it is specific and in the write site. They don't want any polls though, it's too problematic.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Every single car maker does that. And they have had pretty good success with it.

Comment: @ProblematicTitleException nope. Read and learn. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/06/the-pontiac-aztek-and-the-perils-of-design-by-committee.html

Comment: @JeffAtwood I am just saying that your analogy is a poor one since many best selling "trucks" are just truck bodies slapped onto slightly modified car chassis.

Comment: @hammar i have corrected my ill-formed acronym. so i guess the simple answer is no?

Comment: I'm all for `poll.stackoverflow.com`, but I fear it would be more interesting than useful or reliable.

Comment: There's always Quora if [you like to ask these questions :P](http://www.quora.com/Quora-Question-Policies-Guidelines/Are-poll-and-survey-questions-allowed-on-Quora)